# How does one read encrypted e-mail sent from thunderbird

Tags: email

I sent a test message to another yahoo mail account to see if encrypted e-mail works. When sent the test message, it came through on yahoo mail as 2 attachments, the first of which could not be decrypted by thunderbird and the second, telling me the file already exists in a huge window, and that I have to rename it.. which after doing it did absolutely nothing..

So to the point.. once you send an e-mail encrypted thunderbird/enigmail, how does the person receiving the e-mail actually get to read it?

Comment: The recipient of the encrypted message should have a private key/cert that will decrypt the message on their end.  If they don't then the message isn't decrypt-able and they won't be able to read it.

Comment: a private key? Do I have that? I'm doing this all from here so if theres a private key, then I probably have it, right?

Comment: Are you the recipient or the sender of the encrypted message?

Comment: actually both.. I'm using 2 different accounts to send and receive.. so I don't send a message and no one can read it.. LoL!! I just want to know how to decrypt a message sent at yahoo, like if someone's getting it

Comment: it asked me to save the file somewhere to read it but I don't know what comes next adn there's nothing on the internet that guides me through this..